# Dirac Delta function in Brillouin zone - Python Coding Problem

Tags: solid-state-physics, computational-physics, dirac-delta-distributions, software

I am confused with the expression of Dirac delta function in the 1st Brillouin zone in python. Suppose we are dealing with a 1D chain with period boundary condition which have 10 sites for instance. Given a general tight-binding Hamiltonian written in this form:

\begin{equation}
H = \sum_i  t_{i,i+1} c^{\dagger}_{i} c_{j}
\end{equation}

We can use Fourier transform to represent this Hamiltonian in momentum space and all the energy in block diagonalize form.
\begin{equation}
H = \sum_{k} E_{k} c^{\dagger}_{k} c_{k} ~~,~~ c^{\dagger}_{i} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{V}} \sum_{k \in \text{B.Z}} e^{-i k \cdot R_{i}} c^{\dagger}_{k}
\end{equation}
where the momentum $k$ lies on the 1st Brillouin zone $[-\pi, \pi]$. We know that the Fourier transform must satisfy the orthogonality condition:
\begin{equation}
\delta(R_i - R_j)  = \frac{1}{V} \sum_{k \in \text{B.Z}} e^{-i k \cdot (R_{i} - R_j)} 
\end{equation}

Having these expressions, I wanna check the orthogonality condition in Python. Firstly, I just consider the $R_j = 0 $ hence $\delta(R_i - 0)  = \frac{1}{V} \sum_{k} e^{-i k \cdot (R_{i})} $. For $R_i$ in 1D chain, it is just the label of sites which are integer $[0,1,2,\ldots,9]$. Having this setup, I just type the following in Python.

```
import numpy as np
k_array = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 10000) # 1st Brillouin zone 
dR = np.linspace(0,9,10) # 10 sites chain
V = k_array.shape[0]
delta = np.array([V**-1 * np.sum( [np.exp(-1.0j * k*r) for k in k_array]) for r in dR]4
```

My expectation is that `delta` will return an array with $[1,0,\ldots, 0]$. This expectation is based on $\delta(R_i - 0) = 1$ when $R_i = 0$. However, the code returns me an array `[1, 1e-4, 1e-4,...]` which is not completely zeros for $R_i \neq R_j$. Hence, may I ask in which part I misunderstand the physical picture or coding? I appreciate any comment.

Comment: $k$ takes discrete values $2\pi n/L$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ (for PBC). In your code you were approximating an integral over the B.Z.

Comment: @MengCheng is right - you have periodic BC imposed, which is the correct thing to do, but then the completeness will hold only for the values of $k$ selected by the periodic BC.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So if I really want to represent the Dirac delta function, should I sum over all Brillouin zone instead of the 1st Brillouin zone? For instance,I need to enlarge the size of momentum space like ```[-10000*np.pi, 10000*np.pi]``` to get a relatively good approximation of Dirac delta.